# Validation problem with XML declaration

Tags: validation

I'm a complete beginner, and having real problems getting my XML declaration to validate to 1.0 strict.  Can anyone help?

I've been told to put  but when I run it through the W3 validator, it adds some stuff, so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0! encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- <?xml version="1.0! encoding="iso-8859-1"?> -->
```

and says I have 3 errors:

String not closed expecting " or ' 
Blank needed here
parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected

all in the same place, at the first 0 in

```
<?xml version="1.0! encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- <?xml version="1.0! encoding="iso-88…
```

Apologies if this is a really stupid question, but this is my first time writing for the web!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `version="1.0!`.

Do you mean `version="1.0"`?

Comment: Oh, I knew it would be something silly! Many thanks for good naturedly helping someone so clueless, you're a lifesaver.